# iOS UI Automation Script to run on device

Tags: ios, mobile-application, ios-ui-automation

Can someone me help how to run an iOS UI Automation Script to run on real devices. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

As part of Instruments, running a UI Automation script against a device is the same process you'd use to do any Instruments profiling. In Xcode, choose the device but instead of building and running on the device, choose "Profile" from the "Product" menu. Choose the UI Automation template and put it  the script you want to run. Now you can run the script and it should control your device like it controls the simulator.

Comment: Is it possible to run the automation without using a real device or a simulator? I got the automation under control by running on command line. I would like to see whether it's passed or not just by looking at the logs.

Answer (score 1):

I Think this should:

Goto Your Xcode

- Select your device
- select correct provisioning Profile in Build Setting
- Now Choose Profile from the Product menu or simply Command key + i.

It will run your script on Device you plugged.